# Why can't I send anything from server to client after receiving an image from client using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-services, sockets

I managed to send an image from client to server, but when I try to send anything from server to client, it doesn't seem to work.

Here's the code:

Client:

```
import socket
import pickle


host = socket.gethostname()

port = 5000

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.connect((host , port))



f = open("test.png", "rb")

while True:

    veri = f.read()

    if not veri:

        break

    s.send(veri)

f.close()

print "image successfully sent"




data = s.recv(1024)
#data_arr=pickle.loads(data)

print "data recieved is :",data


#s.close()
```

Server:

```
import socket
import pickle
from PIL import Image
import os


host = socket.gethostname()

port = 5000

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

s.bind((host, port))

s.listen(5)

client , adress = s.accept()

print "successfully connected to",adress

f = open("server.png", "wb")

while True:

    veri = client.recv(1024)

    if not veri:

        break

    f.write(veri)

f.close()

print "image recieved successfully"


#T= os.path.abspath(f.name)

#print "the path of the image is ",T

#data=pickle.dumps(T)
client.send(str(9))
print "binary data sent"

client.close()
```

The image is successfully sent from client to server, but when I try sending a string, everything stop working.

Comment: Please can you expand upon "everything stopped working", and were there any error messages

Comment: in fact, i keep waiting and i don' t get any errors

Comment: i have to interrupt the process with my keyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import socket

class node(object):
    def __init__(self, nodeType):
        self.port = 80
        self.addr = socket.gethostname()
        if nodeType == "client":
            self.node = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            self.node.connect((self.addr, self.port))

        if nodeType == "server":
            self.serv = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            self.serv.bind((self.addr, self.port))
            self.serv.listen(5)
            self.node, self.addr = self.serv.accept()

    def recv_file(self):
        file = bytearray(self.node.recv(1024))
        while b"\r\n\r\n" not in file:
            file += self.node.recv(1024)

        name = input("File received, enter file name to save!\n>>> ")
        with open(name, "wb") as f:
            f.write(bytes(file))

    def send_file(self, name):
        self.node.sendall(open(name, "rb").read() + b"\r\n\r\n")
        print("The file was successfully sent!")
```

Server:

```
client = node("server")
client.send_file("<File Name>") # use method for sending files
client.recv_file() # use method for reciving files
```

Client:

```
server = node("client")
server.send_file("<File Name>") # use method for sending files
server.recv_file() # use method for reciving files
```